# Inserting a new root element in lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I have an xml file (not necessarily html):

```
<div>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

and I wish to insert a new `html` root element to give

```
<html>
  <div>
   <p>...</p>
  </div>
</html>
```

(I will add `head`, `body` later.) Is there a simple command to insert a new element `html` as new parent of `div` without creating a new tree and copying elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure; just create a `html` element and add the `div` inside it:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as et
>>> t = et.fromstring("<div><p>...</p></div>")
<Element div>
>>> html = et.Element("html")
<Element html>
>>> html.append(t)
>>> et.tostring(html)
b'<html><div><p>...</p></div></html>'
>>>
```

Comment: `html` has a different `ElementTree` from `div`. I was trying to avoid this but maybe it doesn't matter? It would lose any PIs associated with the `div` tree.

Comment: `ElementTree` seems to have a `_setroot()` function, if that helps.

Comment: Thanks - my confusion was that (a) I was trying to add an ElementTree (the result of the parse) - fixed with .getroot() and (b) I think I give too much weight to the ElementTrees (perhaps as a resyult of years of Java)